# How to make kernelspec available to Jupyter and iPython?

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed via `conda install ipython` and `conda install jupyter`. 
My issue is when start ipython notebook, it works fine because there is a kernel:

The output of ipython kernelspec list is:

> Available kernels:
>   python2

When I try to start with `jupyter notebook`, I get issues related to not finding the kernel.

Executing the following: `jupyter kernelspec list`

I get the following:

> [ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
>   [ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
>   No kernels available

How do I get around this?

Comment: Install [kernels](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html) for `jupyter`. Also, installing just jupyter properly should have at least one ipython kernel available for you.